# How should I define models that will be owned by many different models?

Tags: django, django-models

Disclaimer: Django models sometimes confuse the heck out of me.

I have the following situation, which I'll express in JPA as it makes the most sense to me:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    /* fields omitted for brevity */
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity 
public class Location {
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class MultiEvent {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

How would I express the following in Django:

> 1. One User can have many Addresses, but Addresses don't need to have any reference back to their owner.
> 2. One Location has one Address, but again, the Address doesn't need to have any reference back to its owner.
> 3. Similar to the first scenario, one MultiEvent can have many Addresses, but each Address doesn't need to reference the MultiEvent that it belongs to.

How can I create the same scenario in Django? I get confused easily as there isn't a `OneToMany` field nor a `ManyToOne` field in Django, only the `ForeignKey` field. I also can't find the complete documentation for all accepted constructor parameters defined by `ForeignKey` which might explain why I'm feeling a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One User can have many Addresses, but Addresses don't need to have any reference back to their owner.

You will need a foreign key in `Address`, pointing to a `User`. Give it a `related_name` so that you can refer to it in an intuitive way. Something like this,

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='addresses')

u = User()
for a in u.addresses.all(): 
    print a  # loop through all addresses
```

#### One Location has one Address, but again, the Address doesn't need to have any reference back to its owner.

Use a [One to one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#one-to-one-relationships), the back reference you get for free!

#### Similar to the first scenario, one MultiEvent can have many Addresses, but each Address doesn't need to reference the MultiEvent that it belongs to.

Same as the first, `ForeignKey` in `Address` to 'MultiEvent`

Comment: Ok, I guess this answers my question, Django is just a bit confusing with the way models must be defined and the fact that in many cases, you literally _have to_ define a reference backwards though the reference you're defining doesn't really matter. (ie, you must define `user` on the `Address` in order for a `User` to have `addresses`, despite the fact that you don't want an `Address` to have a reference to the owning `User`, as it's a type used by many other types. Weird.)

Answer (score 0):

In django 'oneToMany' works out to ForeignKey.
I find that using related names can help ease confusion in this sense:

```
#models.py
class myModel(Model):
    other_item = field(...)

class otherModel(Model):
    mymodel = ForeignKey(myModel, related_name="otherModels")

#then you can access all the otherModels as:
#the orm adds this attribute to any instantiated models of myModel
#its the equivalent of otherModel.objects.filter(mymodel=model_instance) 
myModelInstance.otherModels.all()
```

Unfortunately this means you always have to declare the relation in the "one" of the oneToMany relationship. But at the end of the day is proper database design.